# Applying conditional formatting using the average of each individual row

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply conditional formatting to a few hundred rows of data, but I want to keep them separate.  Meaning, if I want to color cells based on their proximity to the average value, I want that average value to only be computed using data in its particular row. While my data-set was small, I was simply using the format painter as [Microsoft suggests](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-and-paste-conditional-formatting-to-other-cells-306efe99-f1d5-4a1f-851b-c9695ab05001) (as does one of several answers to [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/867092/apply-conditional-formatting-to-multiple-rows)). Now that I have hundreds of rows, however, I can not manually copy the formatting to each individual row especially because the "clipboard" resets each time.

As Dave J. [mentions](https://superuser.com/a/867589/81403), the only solution to this problem might be to use a macro. Is this true? What can I do?

Comment: Could you show some text data and expected output?

Comment: Have you tried updating the Applies To section in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You could paste (the formatting) into multiple rows at once, but it is easier to simply put all rows in the Applies-to field